# Derivative of diagonal matrix expression: $f(X)=\text{diag}(X)M^T\text{diag}^{-1}(MX)$

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let X be a vector $\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$ and M be a constant matrix $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and given the function $f(X)$ how could i find the derivative of $f(X)$ with respect to $X$? In the expression diag($X$) represents the diagonal matrix of $X$.

$$f(X)=\text{diag}(X)M^T\text{diag}^{-1}(MX)$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you check the parenthesis is correct? 
The shape of output from $f(X)$ is $n\times n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
\def\bx{\boxtimes}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\A{A^{-1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\D{\operatorname{Diag}}
\def\v{\operatorname{vec}}
X &= {\rm Diag}(x) \\
A &= {\rm Diag}(Mx) = A^T \\
F &= XM^T\A \\
}$$
and the symbol $\bx$ for the columnar Khatri-Rao product
$$\eqalign{
A &= \m{a_1&a_2&\ldots&a_n} \;&\in\bbR{m\times n} \\
B^T &= \m{b_1&\,b_2&\ldots&\,b_n} \;&\in\bbR{p\times n} \\
C &= \m{c_1&\,c_2&\ldots&\,c_n} \;&\in\bbR{mp\times n} \\
C &= \LR{B^T\bx A} \;\iff\; c_k &= \LR{b_k\otimes a_k} \\
}$$
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product. The one remarkable property of this product is its ability to vectorize products involving a diagonal matrix
$$\eqalign{
&\v\!\big(A\,\D(x)\;B\,\big) \;=\; (B^T\bx A)\,x \\
}$$
Use the above notation to calculate the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
dF &= dX\,M^T\A + XM^T\,d\A \\
 &= I_n\,\D(dx)\;M^T\A - XM^T\A\,\D(M\,dx)\;\A \\
\\
df &= \v(dF) \\
 &= \LR{\A M\bx I_n}dx - \LR{\A\bx XM^T\A}M\,dx \\
\\
\grad{f}{x} &= \LR{\A M\bx I_n} - \LR{\A\bx F}M \\
\\
}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like to ask you what is In. Is it the Identity Matrix? Also i would like to ask you about the dimension of the derivative, is it $n^2$ x n? And i would like to request you for recommendatios abouts books to study further this topic. Thank you in advance

Comment: The standard text is probably
Magnus and Neudecker's _Matrix Differential Calculus_  And yes, $I_n$ is the identity matrix. $\,(A,F,I_n,X)$ are all $n\times n$ matrices. The vector $f$ has length $n^2$ while the vector $x$ has a length of $n.\;$

Answer (score 1):

One way to simplify the matter is to use subscripts (einstein summation rule) when dealing with matrix function and derivative.

For example your function could be re-writen as such

$$
f(X)_{ij}=X_i M_{ji} (\sum_l M_{jl}X_l)^{-1}
$$

Then you could figure out this partial derivative tensor based on that
$$
\partial f(X)_{ij}/\partial X_k
$$